# Angular 2 Custom Pipe not Updating Until Object Saved

Tags: angular, typescript

I have made a custom Angular 2 pipe to format a phone number from a string of 10 digits to be 'XXX-XXX-XXXX'. The pipe I made works great, but it doesn't update until you edit and then save. It doesn't update on keypress.

I've read a few different places what I could on custom pipes, but I'm not sure which route to go from here. [Here's a plunk with the working custom pipe](https://plnkr.co/edit/5hqGJd?p=preview) and here's the code as well:

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      Phone: <input type="text" [ngModel]="obj.phone | phone" />
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [],
  pipes: [PhoneNumber]
})
export class App {
  public obj: any = {
    phone: '8885552233'
  };
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Pipe:

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'phone'
})
export class PhoneNumber implements PipeTransform{
  transform(value, args) {
    if( value ) {
      var str = "";
        switch( value.length ) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                str = value;
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
            case 6:
                str = value.substring(0, 3) + '-' + value.substring(2, value.length);
                break;
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
            case 10:
                str = value.substring(0, 3) + '-' + value.substring(3, 6) + '-' + value.substring(6);
                break;
        }
        return str;
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

If you have any ideas or any advice, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want to happen. The pipe should only change how the phone number is displayed in the input element or also how it is stored in `obj.phone`?

Comment: You are using a one way binding [ngModel]="obj.phone". Hence when you change data it wont set back to model. Pipe cannot be used during two way binding such as [(ngModel)]="obj.phone"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some action for the `ngModelChange` event

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="obj.phone | phone" (ngModelChange)="obj.phone=$event" />
```

Comment: This does fire an event, but it still doesn't work as expected. I updated the plunk. Check that out again to see what I mean.

Comment: The question "what is expected" is still unanswered (see my comment to your question).

Answer (score 1):

The answer Günter Zöchbauer , solve the problem, but now you say it does not work as expected maybe this helps you, but not if this will be the best approach to what you want

https://plnkr.co/edit/JAxA777p1dX8u2RpmvSA?p=preview

```
.
```

I hope it will help

Comment: I'm glad to help you, but I think the answer @Günter Zöchbauer has to be the accepted good luck

Comment: The problem is you are trying to use pipes in place of directives

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, one a typo-level error, the other more substantial. The typo is that your pipe, on the 4-6 case, should start the second substring at index 3, not 2.

The more substantial error is that your `ngModelChange` handler needs to perform the reverse of the pipe's transform. Every time ngModelChange fires, it's sending the pipe-modified value back into your model data, which then gets sent back out through the pipe for display so you're getting data filtered through repeated applications of the pipe. But - and this is important - you can't just apply a naive exact reversal of the pipe, removing the fourth and 7th characters; the input your ngModelChange handler receives will be the output of the pipe, modified by one input change, and that will often throw off the position of the inserted dashes, if the dashes are even there - what if the input change is a paste of a whole 10 digit number in a previously empty field? Instead, try searching for and removing dashes, wherever they might be.

Comment: What I ended up doing is every time the pipe runs, I removed all the '-' before going into the switch statement. that way I start with just the numbers in the switch statement every time, and know I can start at the same index.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your answers. I ended up using a little bit of @Günter Zöchbauer's answer, with the ngModelChange event, and then had to change the custom pipe to strip out the '-' each time the pipe runs. [I updated my plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/5hqGJd?p=preview) to show the changes.

```
.
```

Again, thanks for the help and hopefully this helps others in the future.